# Ricoh 3503 Scan to folder not working

Tags: scanner

[Foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu6oi.jpg) I have a problem scanning documents to a folder on Ricoh MP3503 printers. The problem is on some windows 10. The folder on the computer is shared. Smb support included. Admin data provided with a password. E-mail scan works. Need help.

Comment: Your photo is in German, could you please add here its translation to English?

Comment: Basic translation is "The connection to the PC has failed, check the settings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information is needed. Start with the following:

1. First, check [the manual pages](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001036/0001036377/view/scanner/unv/0066.htm) for all the related settings. These should be similar for all MP printers.
2. Check that you can successfully access the SMB share from another device - Test with a PC or phone.
3. If step 2 does not work, check that the firewall allows SMB on the Windows 10 PC, or try turning off the firewall temporarily.